# Freemarker max list items

Tags: xml, list, freemarker

I'm making an email with XML import with freemarker.

```
<#list feed.emailinfo.article as artikel>
```

I want max 3 articles (artikelen) displayed, does anybody knows how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<#list feed.emailinfo.article[0..*3] as artikel>
```

The `*` will make sure you don't get index-out-of-bound exceptions.